# Can I make Compiz Scale plugin show minimized windows?

Tags: 10.10, configuration, compiz

Can I make the Compiz Scale plugin show minimized windows as well as maximized ones?  (I'm using Maverick, if that helps.)

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue ? I have this problem in ubuntu mate 16.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, because the version of compiz in Maverick was released before this feature became available in compiz 0.9.x. This feature will most likely be there in Natty, due to a newer version of compiz, but not in Maverick.

Update:
In Natty I'm not seeing this option (though I read about compiz 0.9 getting it. I will have to try to ask Sam about it.

Comment: If I install compiz 0.9.x, will I be able to do this?

Comment: yes, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Is it too unstable?

Comment: for 10.10, yes.